# Error registering COM server when interface derives from IXMLHttpRequest

Tags: visual-c++, com, xmlhttprequest, atl, idl

We've created our own implementation of `IXMLHttpRequest` in a COM server (.exe) like so:

```
interface IMyXMLHttpRequest : IXMLHttpRequest {
    ...
};

coclass MyXMLHttpRequest {
    [default] interface IMyXMLHttpRequest;
};
```

The problem is that when the build tries to register the COM server, we get the error "Error accessing the OLE registry". I debugged the registration code and it is failing in `RegisterTypeLib`. It looks like it is trying to pull in some of the type information relating to `IXMLHttpRequest` and (guessing here) can't change some registry keys related to that interface.

Is it just plain wrong to derive from `IXMLHttpRequest`? Should we be deriving from `IDispatch` instead and making our class use a dual interface? Or is it possible to derive from `IXMLHttpRequest` and we're just doing it wrong?

**Update:** I've uploaded a [reproducible test case](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngt6yo35d66yb9z/COMServerTest.zip). I simply generated an ATL COM server using the Visual Studio wizard, and then I created a new interface derived from `IXMLHttpRequest` and a coclass that implements it. The registration fails as I described. If I change the interface to derive from `IDispatch` then it works fine. 100% reproducible on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010, running with elevated privileges.

Comment: This project is too weird for me to stick in fork into. Your test program is an out-of-process server. Your .rgs file is empty. You didn't embed the type library in the resources. No idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: The app we are developing where the problem occurs uses an out-of-process server. I'm not sure what's weird about that. The project I uploaded is *exactly* the boilerplate that Visual Studio 2010 generates (including the empty .rgs) with only the .idl file modified. I don't know why the type library needs to be embedded in the resources. Just open the project in VS 2010, build and the error occurs. To me that's what a reproducible test case should do.

Comment: Regarding the type library: my (quite possibly faulty) understanding is that the .idl file is used to generate a type library which is embedded in the .exe resources. I can certainly see a type library in the .exe when I open it in Visual Studio. I would have thought that embedding a type library in the resources is only necessary when using a type library obtained by other means (i.e. not compiled from an .idl file in the project). Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -2147319780.

Just for the record, the error is `0x8002801C` `TYPE_E_REGISTRYACCESS` "Error accessing the OLE registry."

As you already identified, the problem is around inheriting from `IXMLHttpRequest` interface which is defined outside of the type library. Extending an interface through inheritance is basically not a good idea in first place. Yes it is possible and it makes sense, however as soon as you approach putting this into a type library and having external references, you might be starting hitting weird issues.

As soon as you referenced `IXMLHttpRequest`, MIDL compiler is trying to put it into your type library as well. You can witness this by looking into intermediate build files:

[image: An unexpected copy of IXMLHttpRequest]

It is not what you wanted, is it? You just wanted to reference it because it is already defined and hosted by another type library in `msxml6.dll` file in system32 (syswow64) directory.

The main question is why you want to inherit from `IXMLHTTPRequest`. Why you think a "normal" separate new IDispatch-derived interface is not good enough here? You can still implement `IXMLHTTPRequest` on this COM class as well. And you would not get into this trouble in first place then.

Anyway, the building problem is that on IDL the compiler sees definition of `IXMLHTTPRequest` coming from Windows SDK file directly.

You want to change your IDL file as follows:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
//import "ocidl.idl"; // <<--- Make direct IXMLHTTPRequest definition invisible

[
    uuid(7397D60F-A428-42C5-B698-9FA850638074),
    version(1.0),
]
library COMServerTestLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    importlib("msxml6.dll"); // <<--- Reference MSXML type library to import the right interface
```

In your C++ file you want to make the interface visible for C++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <msxml6.h> // <<--- Re-add IXMLHTTPRequest definition for C++ code
#include "COMServerTest_i.h"
```

Your project is buildable again from here.

Comment: Good stuff. We changed to deriving from `IDispatch` already but I wanted to a) check that that was the right approach and b) understand better the behavior I was observing.

Comment: Is there any way of achieving what importlib does when using attributed C++ code? I have a very large COM library which is importing msxml and redefining all its interfaces in our component's tlb, which is causing problems.

Comment: You can inject `importlib` into IDL using [`idl_quote`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5cy953h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)